# How to create grid in d3.js by reading x and y points json file

Tags: d3.js, line

i am looking forward to create 10 rows and 10 columns grid in d3.js but here the x and y line points should read from json file. i not getting how to do this.

```
-------------------------------
|       |      |       |     |
-------------------------------
|       |      |       |     |
------------------------------
|       |      |       |     |
------------------------------
```

```
    var width = 500;
    var height = 500;

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);//Create line element inside SVG
    svg.append("line")
       .attr("x1", 100)
       .attr("x2", 500)
       .attr("y1", 50)
       .attr("y2", 50)
       .attr("stroke", "black")


        var svg1= d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

    //Create line element inside SVG
    svg1.append("line")
       .attr("x1", 0)
       .attr("x2", 0)
       .attr("y1", 0)
       .attr("y2", 200)
       .attr("stroke", "black")
```

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zppLjvjh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json should contain all positions of the grid like this :

```
var inputs = [{  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 50},
              {  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 60,  "y2": 60},
              ....
```

Then you can reuse your attributes to draw the lines :

```
.attr("x1", function(d) {
    return d.x1;
 })
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/n0sauja1/

Comment: awesome Tim B.. columns is not there

Comment: Hi Tim B please can you share your mail id

Comment: Tim B can you share your mail id please

Comment: when i use .attr( 'transform', 'scale( 1 -1 )' ); the draw went off why

Comment: Create a new question for that

Comment: I am trying to this one actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997405/how-to-invert-the-grid-in-d3-js/46038329#46038329

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",500).attr("height", 500);

        var inputs = [  

       {  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 50},
       {  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 60,  "y2": 60},
       {  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 70,  "y2": 70},
       {  "x1": 100,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 80,  "y2": 80},
       {  "x1": 100,  "x2": 100,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 80},
       {  "x1": 160,  "x2": 160,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 80},  
       {  "x1": 220,  "x2": 220,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 80},  
       {  "x1": 280,  "x2": 280,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 80}, 
       {  "x1": 340,  "x2": 340,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 80}, 
       {  "x1": 400,  "x2": 400,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 80},
       {  "x1": 460,  "x2": 460,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 80},
       {  "x1": 500,  "x2": 500,  "y1": 50,  "y2": 80},
       ] 


         svg.selectAll("line").data(inputs).enter().append("line")

         .attr("x1", function(d) {
           return d.x1;
         })
         .attr("x2", function(d) {
           return d.x2;
         })
         .attr("y1", function(d) {
           return d.y1;
         })
         .attr("y2", function(d) {
           return d.y2;
         })
         .attr("stroke", "red")
```